# Test if function returns nothing powershell and return "No Results found"

Tags: powershell

I have a script I wrote that returns any AD group with part of a name in the search parameters to save the time of looking through 1000+ groups.
I want to know, if my function doesn't return anything, how do I test for that and return Write-Host "No results found" instead of just giving a blank screen without a result.

The function is get-adgroup -filter {name -like $nameentered}

I don't know how to look this up, all no result returned always shows broken scripts when I looked it up here, hopefully i'm not asking a stupid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use `if \ else`?

```
if ( $x = get-adgroup -filter {name -like $nameentered} ) {
     $x
} else {
     Write-Host 'nothing found'
}
```

what this does - it checks if `$x` contains anything if it does - outputs it

Comment: While it's a neat trick that assignments will output their assignee when used as an expression, it makes code harder to read.  I'd advise assigning `$x` before the block.

Comment: So I tried and it returns nothing found even if there is something foundEDIT; NEVER MIND IT WORKS THANKS! SUPER SIMPLE!

Comment: Did, super easy if stated, just didn't know its that easy, thought i'd need to check for null or something

Comment: yeah, you would need if you'd set strick mode, but by default powershell is easy on admins ;)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I guess that's personal preference. But its nice to know that this is possible. But I probably agree with you.

Comment: @user2237848 PowerShell is "truthy", meaning `$null`, `0`, `""` (empty string), all evaluate to `$false`.  Presence of objects evaluates to `$true`